# Error in optim R - cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to estimate the parameter a, b, c, and s by using optim in R. Here is my code.

```
age <- c(0,30,60,90)
Dx <- c(49294.57, 2975.1, 11456.38, 2977.08)
Ex <- c(1572608.38, 1531956.05, 650404.58, 9728.47)

log_lik <- function(par,x,y,z){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  s <- par[4]
  mu <- (a*exp(b*x))/(1+s * (a)/(b) * (exp(b*x)-1)) + c
  lambda <- mu * z
  
  lnL <- sum(y*log(lambda) - log(factorial(y)) - lambda)
  -lnL
}

optim(c(1,1,1,1),log_lik, x = age, y = Dx, z = Ex)
```

But, I get an error

```
Error in optim(c(1, 1, 1, 1), log_lik, x = age, y = Dx, z = Ex) : 
  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
```

I have tried several initial values, but still get the same error. Can you solve this problem? Or maybe there is another code to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is already in the `factorial(y)` part, this is infinite from the very start, you have too big values.

Comment: So, how to solve this problem? Because the equation consist of ```factorial(y)```

Comment: Don't use `log(factorial(x))`; rather, use `lfactorial(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from calculating the factorial of a large number then taking its log. The factorial number is too high for R to recognise as a finite number, but its log is not. In this situation, we can get the same result as `log(factorial(y))` by using the `lgamma` function.

This is not a hack; the `factorial` function in R is just a thin wrapper for the `gamma` function:

```r
factorial
#> function (x) 
#> gamma(x + 1)
```

So we can get a function that does the same as `log(factorial(y))` without the need to actually go through the step of calculating extremely high numbers then taking their log, like this:

```r
log_factorial <- function(x) lgamma(x + 1)
```

Which we can see gives us the correct results:

```r
log(factorial(21))
#> [1] 45.38014

log_factorial(21)
#> [1] 45.38014
```

But allows us to input higher numbers without generating infinities.

```r
log(factorial(200))
#> [1] Inf

log_factorial(200)
#> [1] 863.232
```

So we can change your code slightly to:

```r
log_lik <- function(par,x,y,z){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  s <- par[4]
  mu <- (a*exp(b*x))/(1+s * (a)/(b) * (exp(b*x)-1)) + c
  lambda <- mu * z
  
  lnL <- sum(y*log(lambda) - lgamma(y + 1) - lambda)
  -lnL
}
```

And now we get:

```r
optim(c(1,1,1,1), log_lik, x = age, y = Dx, z = Ex)
#> $par
#> [1]  0.6114036  1.1267546 -0.5800334  1.9163744
#> 
#> $value
#> [1] 15828.8
#> 
#> $counts
#> function gradient 
#>      161       NA 
#> 
#> $convergence
#> [1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forget to say that all of the parameters must be positive. From this result, parameter c is negative. How can I modify the code?

Comment: @mathz the formula in your function gives these results with those values of age, Dx and Ex. I don't know what you're trying to calculate or what paper you got this from, so I can't tell you anything other than that. If the results don't make sense, then either there is a problem with your data, your formula or your application of this model to these data. Without knowing what you are trying to do, I cannot help.

Comment: Why are you defining the `log_factorial` function when there is `lfactorial` out of the box?

Comment: @nicola I didn't know it existed, so thanks for pointing that out. Interestingly, the code for it is exactly the same as the function I defined. Ah well, always learning!

Answer (score 0):

The optimization cannot be done because you have very large values, which results in infinite or NA values. One option could be to rescale your variables, for ex if your variable is naturally in the range around 1 million, divide all the values by 1 million. For ex.

```
age=age/1e2
Dx=Dx/1e5
Ex=Ex/1e6
```

now the optimization works and returns

```
$par
[1]  1.418161 37.235806 -1.104942 31.443860

$value
[1] 1.421373

$counts
function gradient 
     479       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

Warning messages:
1: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
2: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
3: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
4: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
5: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
6: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
7: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
8: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
9: In log(lambda) : NaNs produced
```

there are still issues with the `log(lambda)` part, since it can happen that lambda is negative, which is an issue. You may have to use constrained optimization to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that the value of lambda that maximises

```
  lnL <- sum(y*log(lambda) - log(factorial(y)) - lambda)
```

is the same value that maximises

```
  lnL_2 <- sum(y*log(lambda) - lambda)
```

so you can optimise lnL_2 instead of lnL. See, e.g, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399613/how-to-derive-the-likelihood-and-loglikelihood-of-the-poisson-distribution/2399663) over at Math Stackexchange for derivation.